# How do I change the color of a word inside a listbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, colors, listbox

I made a Form with a TextBox that accepts a word and searches a bunch of sentences to see if any of them contains that word .After that I have to appear those sentences and highlight the word .My plan is to make a ListBox and add the sentences inside of it. My problem is how to highlight the word (by changing the color I suppose) so it can be distinguished.

Is there a preferable way?
I chose ListBox so I can select the sentence I'm looking for.

***Edit***

According to @Thorsten Dittmar directions a create an owner drawn list box.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<string> _items;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _items = new List<string>();
            _items.Add("One");
            _items.Add("Two");
            _items.Add("Three");
            listBox1.DataSource = _items;
        }

        private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            e.DrawBackground();
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
            e.Graphics.DrawString(_items[e.Index],
                new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif,
                    8, FontStyle.Bold),
                    new SolidBrush(Color.Red), e.Bounds);
        }
    }
```

How I'm going to split the sentence in order to draw only one word?

***Edit2***

The way I finally did it was to make two seperate components, to compine my options.
One was a `ListBox` with all the sentences colored and the option to select one
of those and the other one a `RichBox` with separate colored words since is to difficult
to achieve that with the `ListBox` (for me a least).

The way I accomplished that was by using a boolean array pointing which word should 
be colored in each sentence.

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
  if (segments[i]) //<-boolean array
  {
     rich.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
     rich.AppendText(words[i] + " ");
     rich.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
  }
  else
  {
    rich.AppendText(words[i] + " ");
  }
}
```

Comment: We're talking winforms? just making sure.

Comment: @Baboon a `Window System Form`

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91747/background-color-of-a-listbox-item-winforms).

Comment: @YouennBouglouan Sorry can't find the way to highlight only a part of a `List Item`.

Comment: I've edited my answer to outline an algorithm you could use to render the list items the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way of doing it in Windows Forms. You'd have to render the list items manually (create an owner drawn list box). In WPF this would be an easy task.

**EDIT**
Drawing only part of a string in a different font is not an easy task. What I'd try is the following:

Introduce tokens that tell you "bold start" and "bold end" - a bit like in HTML. Let's call them the same as in HTML. So your string could look like this:

```
Hello, I am <b>bold</b> text<b>!</b>
```

Now I'd tokenize my string into text that is non-bold and text that is bold. I'd get the following parts:

```
Hello, I am
bold
text
!
```

Now I'd draw each part using the following algorithm:

1. Draw string in current format at current position x
2. increase position x by width of the string drawn in step 1
3. change formatting according to upcoming string
4. goto 1

In step 2 the `Graphics.MeasureString` method would be called to get the width of the string.

Doing this for the 4 sample parts above would result in:

Hello, I am
Hello, I am **bold**
Hello, I am **bold** text
Hello, I am **bold** text **!**

Comment: If I create an owner drawn ListBox could I be able to highlight an individual word of ListItem and not the entire thing?

Comment: Well, as you'd be drawing the text and background yourself, you could sure come up with a solution that renders one word bold or changes the background. But even when drawing the individual list items yourself, there's no builtin solution to to that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple TextBox can have its Foreground property set, but it applies to the entire text within the TextBox.

If you want specific words to be "highlighted", you either need to split the sentence in several TextBoxes (dirty), or make use of a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tdc88y7.aspx)

Comment: He doesn't want to highlight the word in the text box, but, as he said, in a list box.

Comment: Yes you are right ,but if there is a preferable way or an alternative I would like to know it.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar he can customize the ListBoxItem to use a RichTextBox.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156141/c-sharp-custom-listbox-gui boils down to: inherit ListBox and override OnDrawItem.

Comment: So? I know that a you can have owner drawn list boxes - that's what I suggested. Where's the `RichTextBox` in the link you provided?

Comment: My point was: what you're looking for is a RichTextBox. HOW you're going to make it fit in is another question. Now, @ThorstenDittmar, stop being aggressive, this is not the place.

Comment: I'm not being aggressive at all! Sorry if I came across like that. I was just wondering how he should use `RichTextBoxes` in `ListViewItems` in Windows Forms and the link you provided doesn't tell me that.

Comment: I provided the link to give a direction for infos because RichTextBox may not be very straightforward at first... Regarding how to fit it in a List(Box/View)Item, I don't know of *A* way, but I can think of several workarounds, and in winforms it always takes some effort.

Answer (score 0):

Giannosfor, in response to your comment, you'll have to use the parameter e of the event handler to choose which item you want to hightlight ([link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91747/background-color-of-a-listbox-item-winforms)).

Look at the response from Shadow Wizard and particularly at the use of e.Index.

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
...
g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(color), e.Bounds);
```

Variable g represent the graphic part of your current item e. Method FillRectangle allows you to change the color of the item's background.

**Edit 1:**

I tried to do as you say in the comment below but it seems there is no way to hightlight only a part of a string using ListBox. To me it seems the only control that is able to support that is the RichTextBox. A solution might be to implement your own user control in the form of a list of RichTextBoxes.

Comment: My problem is exactly that, how to define a specific graphic part (I mean in code) of the current item `e` in order to change the background? If my current item is "The Dog" i want to highlight it likes this "The `Dog`" not the entire sentence. If you can help me I'll appreciate.

Comment: I've edited my answer to give you an idea of how this could be done.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Thorsten Dittmar answer, I developed pretty much exactly what you are looking for in a single ListBox. You can find it at https://advancedlistbox.codeplex.com/.