# C# custom Control Group as ListView Row

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm trying to create a custom `ListView` WinForms control so that each row has a title, subtitle, image icon, and action icon. [There are many answers on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156141/c-sharp-custom-listbox-gui) that describe how to override the `OnDrawItem` method, but what I want is behavior too, i.e. be able to click on an icon in a row and have an event handler.

Is there any way to put a control group as a row element?

Comment: Why not use something that's already [available out there for free](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView)?

Comment: @Jason [take a look at this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532639/complex-ui-inside-listboxitem#).

Comment: @Aeron it's evident that you don't understand sarcasm.

Answer (score 0):

I put it into answer as I have no way to add image in a comment.

Do you wish to get such effect:

[image]

If yes, change ListView.View to Tile. You don't have to use owner draw if this met your requirement.

Comment: This is a good start, but what about behavior? I'm looking for something that allows me to fire events on click of the icon or on mouse over the title, etc.